# can we use value of a variable into a function into another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mern

here I am getting the Customer data from the database and I store it into **custDetail** variable, I know it's a local variable how can I use it as a global variable.

```
 const dashboardReq = async (req, res, next) => {


try {
    const regCust = await registeredUser.findOne({ mobile: req.params.mobile });

if (regCust == null) {
  console.log("No user found");
} else {
  const custDetail = await registeredUser.findOne(req.params);  **/// here I store the data into variable ** 

res.status(201).json({
  status: "success",
  data: { custDetail },
});


 } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: "fail",
      data: next(error),
    });
  }
};
```

now I want to use the value of **custDetail** variable into another function
here is the code

```
const gasService = async (req, res, next , dashboardReq ) => {



 try {
    const { customerNo, bookingNo, bookingDate } = req.body;
    const userName = dashboardReq.name;   **/// here is try to get value** 
    const userMobile = dashboardReq.mobile; **/// here is try to get value** 
    const newGasService = await gasData.create({
      userName,
      userMobile,
      customerNo,
      bookingNo,
      bookingDate,
    });

res.status(201).json({
  status: "success",
  data: { gasService: newGasService },
});


 } 

catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: "fail",
      data: next(error),
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: You need to use a session to store data like that. http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html

Comment: @cmgchess Nope, OP is creating a web server, and each user request would overwrite the outside variable.

Comment: ah yeah i thought he was using in 1 go

Comment: I think you'll need to use a session.  Are you using one already?  something like express-session.  And then you'll have a `req.session` and you can store your own stuff in it like `req.session.custDetail = custDetail`.  But be careful - your server should be stateless (as much as practical)  Here you have one request dependent on what happens in a previous request.  For that you should have a user logged in with a secure session.  Otherwise, maybe pass things along in a query.

Comment: can provide the code

Answer (score -1):

You can initialize `custDetail` outiside the scope of `dashboardReq` function (before it), `let custDetail;` and then assign the value inside the function as `custDetail = await registeredUser.findOne(req.params);` and then reuse it anywhere including `gasService` function

Comment: Although technically true, the implications of storing the custDetails in an outer scope may expose the variable to handlers for different requests - for different users, potentially exposing user information to the wrong user or something.

Comment: @Wyck how would using a session act differently when both methods make the custDetail be accessible everywhere?

Comment: showing error : - TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;name&#39; of undefined

Comment: a session asks the server to create a context object and returns an ID for it.  Subsequent requests can refer to that same ID and thereby the server will access the same context object.  Multiple users can have separate sessions and the ID can be negotiated in a cryptographically secure way.  Using a global variable would just present a singleton context object for the whole server process.  Since the custDetail is based on client req.params, it is likely desirable that a request from you shouldn't interfere with a request from me, for example.  But with a global, they would interfere.

Comment: @OmarKeshk TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;name&#39; of undefined

Comment: @Wyck thanks for explaining, should I delete the answer, since it's not correct?

Comment: @MR_HACK the only place where you're trying to read a "name" property is with dashboardReq wich you're not providing where it came from

Comment: I don't think you need to delete the answer.  It's technically a viable solution to the problem of sharing a variable - making it global.  I just think it should come with a warning that making a variable global in a web server typically means that every request sees the same value for that variable, and requests from one client may then interfere with requests from another client.  Depending on the nature of the data, that may not be a bad thing.  If it not user-sensitive it may be fine.  Just warranted a big caveat I think.